# Applying shadow to UITextView.layer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i want to apply shadow on `UITextView` to give a look like `UITextField`.Any Idea?
I am using

```
textView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.8;
textView.layer.shadowColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
textView.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0, 0);
textView.layer.shadowRadius=3;
textView.layer.cornerRadius=3;
```

but it gives shadow to the text of `UITextView` if the `UITextView` background is transparent.
so is there any idea how to give shadow to layer of `UITextView` like this->

[image]

Comment: try with this [textView setClipsToBounds:NO];

Comment: its working but i don't need this because the content of textView is going out of the bounds so it is give a bad look, any other solution?

Answer (score 9):

```
    // Add shadow
    [textView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [textView.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
    [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
    textView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [textView.layer setShadowRadius:2.0f];
    textView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    textView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    textView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Hi iCode, I checked ur code but there is a issue if i set setMasksToBounds:NO then text height is greater then textView height then text goes out from textview and if i set setMasksToBounds:YES then shadow goes away.

Comment: can i see more of your code? have you tried adding textView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

Comment: This code adds outside shadow for TextView control, but not inside, which author of question meant. I have also noticed, that you are making the double assignment to the same properties but in different ways in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The class doesn't specify such a property. You will have to create it yourself. In order to create it with code, you will have to use the ***QuartzCore*** framework. First you import it to your file and then you can set the following properties:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textView.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This code supposes that you have your textview set up with the name: *textView*. Just change the cornerRadius to fit what you need. This makes the textView show like the picture you showed.

Comment: how to do that? do you mean to put a image in the background of textView?

Comment: actually put an image behind your textView if you plan to use your app for iOS 4.x. Then you just make your textView's background color a clearColor

Comment: i know that solution but i do not want to use that method

Comment: Why would you not want to do it like _that_?

Comment: i want to make textView that looks like `UITextField`

Comment: Posting it as an answer in a sec.